# ¿Cómo hago para que se me agregue un usuario único desde android studio a mi bd en mysql?

Tags: php, java, mysql, android-studio

Pues ya le puse la llave primaria en mi bd, pero quisiera que el usuario sepa que ya existe ese usuario.  Esta es mi conexión para que inserte.

```php
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$contra = sha1($_POST['contra']);
if (repetido($usuario,$contra,$conexion) == 1) {
  echo 2;
} else {
  $consulta = "insert into usuario values('".$usuario."','".$nombre."','".$contra."')";
  mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die(mysqli_error());
  mysqli_close($conexion);
} 
function repetido($usu,$pass,$conexion) {
  $sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios where usuario = '$user'and contra='$pass'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: En lugar de return 1 cámbialo por un echo y el mensaje que deseas mostrar

Comment: Creo que sería más conveniente si solo revisas el usuario, porque con tu verificación actual podría registrarse 2 o más veces usando contraseñas diferentes.